# Checkout / Merge Remote Git Branch

Tags: git

I have a Git remote/master branch on which there are only two commits made by me. A colleague apparently made a branch out of my very first commit and pushed to the repository. Now, i made a second commit after 5 days with lots of changes and pushed into the Repository. Meanwhile, the branch from my colleague contains a couple of commits as well. I am supposed to merge the branches now, but i am afraid that doing a merge would somehow mess up and i might loose my local / messup with the remote.

I know this is a simple task and answered a lot of times, but i am scared to perform the merges . I would really appreciate if somebody could tell me the steps to do the merge properly.

Comment: This doesn't sound too out of the ordinary. Just make a test branch and give it a go. You can look at the commit history to see if the changes are as you like. Follow any standard Git how-to article. You don't need us to rewrite one.

Comment: That's a good tip to try out with the test branch. Thanks man. Probably i am too stressed. I will try it out now and update here